# Waiting for multiple ipc calls to complete before continuing in electron/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ipc, redux, electron

I'm working on an app in Electron, React and Redux. At the program start, I'm making a few asynchronous ipc calls between the render process and the main process and save the results in the store.

```
// in the main app component
componentWillMount() {
    const { store } = this.context;
    store.dispatch(fetchOptions());
    store.dispatch(fetchRequirements());
    store.dispatch(fetchStats());
    /* miracle function */
},

// actions.js
export function fetchOptions() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestOptions());
        ipcRenderer.on('sendOptions', function(event, arg) {
            dispatch(receiveOptions(arg));
        });
        ipcRenderer.send('requestOptions', '');
    };
}
// others accordingly
```

`receiveOptions(arg)`, `receiveRequirements(arg)` and `receiveStats(arg)` are action creators and finally the reducer will save the responses in the store.

Directly after `store.dispatch(fetchStats())`, I want to dispatch another action to make some calculations based on the values that were loaded into the store. However, this action will usually be dispatched before the responses from ipc arrive.

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/723) with a similar problem, but they are making api calls with `fetch` instead of ipc messages, and I wouldn't know how to apply their idea to my problem.

So here is my question: how can I make the program wait for responses from all the channels before continuing?

Edit: When I set a time out of length 0 for the dispatches after the ipc calls, it works at least with immediate responses, but of course it doesn't help when the responses take a bit longer.

```
store.dispatch(fetchOptions());
store.dispatch(fetchRequirements());
store.dispatch(fetchStats());

setTimeout(function() {
    store.dispatch(calculateThis());
    store.dispatch(calculateThat());
}, 0);
```

Comment: What is the return type of the fetch-functions? If they are promises, you can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to do something -- like dispatch an action -- when they are all resolved. If they don't return promises, maybe you can make them do that?

Comment: The fetch functions do not return promises, and I really wouldn't know how to make them do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An example using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

#### Assumption

I'm not familiar with how your `icpRenderer` works, or exaclty when the dispatching is completed. I am going to **assume** that the dispatch is completed after  the call `dispatch(receiveOptions(arg))` returns in

```
    ipcRenderer.on('sendOptions', function(event, arg) {
        dispatch(receiveOptions(arg));
    });
```

*If `dispatch()` is asynchronous, this will not work* (unless you wait to resolve the promise until after `dispatch()` is done).

#### If my assumption is correct

you should be able to <s>return</s> receive a "promise" (and resolve it) like this

```
    // actions.js
    export function fetchOptions(promise) {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(requestOptions());
            ipcRenderer.on('sendOptions', function(event, arg) {
                dispatch(receiveOptions(arg));
                if (promise) promise.resolve(); // Resolve the promise
            });
            ipcRenderer.send('requestOptions', '');
        }
    }
    // return Promises others accordingly
```

(Note that you may call fetchOptions without passing a "promise", because we only call promise.resolve() if promise is present. Hence, this should not complicate your existing code.)

In order to wait for the promises to resolve, you can do like this

```
    // in the main app component
    componentWillMount() {
        const { store } = this.context;
        const promises = [
            new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                store.dispatch(fetchOptions({resolve, reject}))),
            new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                store.dispatch(fetchRequirements({resolve, reject}))),
            new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                store.dispatch(fetchStats({resolve, reject})))
        ];
        Promise.all(promises).then(() =>
            // Dispatch another action after the first three dispatches are completed.
        );
    },
```

The code didn't turn out super clean, but hopefully it will at least work.

Comment: Thanks. Your assumption is right: `ipcRenderer.send` sends a message onthe channel `requestOptions` while `ipcRenderer.on` opens a listener on the channel `sendOptions` and sends the response `args` to the dispatcher.

Comment: Good! Let me know if this worked to solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work. The dispatch function from Redux expects an action with the format {type: receiveOptions, options: args} (for example), which is commonly created with an action creator function, in this case requestOptions(), receiveOptions() and fetchOptions. Through the Thunk middleware it is possible to write action creators that can also dispatch actions. fetchOptions() can't be dispatched when wrapped in a Promise, and the function can't be called directly without dispatch(). I also tried to put the Promise within dispatch => {}, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: OK. Why is it that `fetchOptions()` can't be dispatched when wrapped in a Promise?

Comment: Well, it is possible to return a Promise from a thunk, like this example I found: `function fetchPosts(subreddit) { return function (dispatch) { dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit)); return fetch(...).then(response => response.json()).then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))}}` But I can't figure out how to apply that to ipcRenderer, since that function doesn't return a promise.

Comment: When I try your solution, this action is generated: `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}` (no type), and I get this error message: `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Comment: I see. What are you doing inside `Promise.all(promises).then(() => ...` ?

Comment: I load some values from the store and dispatch another two actions, but that's not where the code breaks.

Comment: I see now the error in my code, you need to return a function from the `fetchOptions()` function. I've made an edit to my answer, where we pass the promise to into `fetchOptions()`, and leaving the return type the same as it was in your example.

Comment: Awesome. One little note: I said we pass a "promise" into `fetchOptions()`, but in reality we are just passing a simple object with two methods, which can resolve or reject the actual Promise. Anyway, great that it finally worked!